# Circular double linked list with smart pointers in c++

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Is it possible to create a circular doubly-linked list using smart pointers in C++

```
struct Node {
  int val;
  shared_ptr<Node> next;
  weak_ptr prev;
};

shared_ptr<Node> head;
```

But this will have a circular reference of shared pointers and thus not deallocate correctly.

Comment: You're using weak pointers so it is fine, take into account that shared pointers may be slow.

Comment: But remember its a circular linked list.  The last node's next pointer points to the first which (transitively) will point to the last node

Answer (score 2):

Make the circular linked list a class itself (with whatever operations you need to build it, like append).  Have its destructor break the link by setting tail->next = nullptr.  It should not matter which link you break, so if you're not using a head and tail, just set any one of them nullptr, and you're good.

In my testing, I made a circular linked list, and the nodes did not destruct.  Then at the end, I added tail->next = nullptr before it exited, and all the destructors fired correctly.

Comment: This.  In the constructor or in the node-adding code, you have to manually set the shared_ptr that produces the cycle, rather than setting it through an allocation, so symmetry requires that, in the destructor, you have to manually reset it to destroy the cycle.

Comment: @AikenDrum Rule of Three applies if you need to implement a destructor. For simpler and more robust code, it is better to follow the Rule of Zero.

Comment: @jxh It's impossible to create a circular list without construction.  If there's no ctor, .add() has to conditionally create the extra link.  That's just deferred construction.  The caller triggers construction indirectly on the first add().  Technically, for symmetry, the caller would need to call .remove()/.reset(), which would destroy the link.  However, they don't _want_ to, so we'll to do it for them in a dtor.  

"Rule" of Zero/Three are not really rules, nor is choosing one over the other.  Simple, robust code comes from common sense and pragmatism, not any "Rule" someone thought up.

Comment: @jxh Not to mention that I'm pretty sure it's not possible to use the default copy constructor on this data structure, so there's Rule of Zero out the window anyway.

Answer (score 1):

My original posted answer was rather light on details. This one gives a proper explanation of how you can achieve a circular linked list without a memory leak and still adhere to the Rule of Zero. The answer is basically the same, using a sentinel, but the mechanism is a little more involved than I had originally let on.

The trick is to use a sentinel type that behaves just like a list node, but in fact does not really have a shared pointer to the head of the list. To achieve this, the node class should be separated into a behavior object and a state object.

```
class NodeState {
    std::shared_ptr<Node> next_;
    std::weak_ptr<Node> prev_;
    int value_;
    NodeState (int v) : value_(v) {}
    NodeState (std::shared_ptr<Node> p) : next_(p), prev_(p) {}
    //...
};

class Node {
    virtual ~Node () = default;
    virtual NodeState & state () = 0;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> & next () { return state().next_; }
    std::weak_ptr<Node> & prev () { return state().prev_; }
    int & value () { return state().value_; }
    void insert (const std::shared_ptr<Node> &p) {
        //...
    }
};
```

Now, you can define a node implementation and a sentinel implementation.

```
class NodeImplementation : public Node {
    NodeState state_;
    NodeState & state () { return state_; }
    NodeImplementation (int v) : state_(v) {}
    //...
};

class NodeSentinel : public Node {
    List &list_;
    NodeSentinel (List &l) : list_(l) {}
    NodeState & state () { return list_.sentinel_state_; }
};
```

The list itself contains a `NodeState` used by the sentinel object. Upon initialization, the list creates a sentinel object and initializes its state.

```
class List {
    //...
    NodeState sentinel_state_;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> head () { return sentinel_state_.next_; }
    std::shared_ptr<Node> sentinel () {
        return std::shared_ptr<Node>(head()->prev());
    }
    //...
public:
    List () : sentinel_state_(std::make_shared<NodeSentinel>(*this)) {}
    //...
    void push_front (int value) {
        head()->insert(std::make_shared<NodeImplementation>(value));
    }
    void push_back (int value) {
        sentinel()->insert(std::make_shared<NodeImplementation>(value));
    }
    //...
};
```

So, what does this organization do? It avoids the issue of a circular reference by using a sentinel node to act as the break. While the tail of the list points to the sentinel object, the sentinel object itself does not point to anything. Instead, it uses the state of the list itself to determine its next and previous neighbors.

[image: List->A->B->C->Sentinel]

Thus, the circular shared pointers only persists as long as the list exists. Once the list is destroyed, `Item A` loses its reference, and via the domino effect, `Sentinel` itself will be destroyed.

A fundamental point is that the sentinel object itself must never be exposed to the user of the list interface directly. It should remain internal to the list object at all times. It essentially represents `end()` in an STL like container, and logically, it can never be removed from the list (until the list itself is destroyed). In practice, this means removal operations on the list need to exit early if the passed in iterator represents the sentinel.

<kbd>[Demo](https://ideone.com/pzhbct)</kbd>

<kbd>[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##nVXJbtswEL37K6Yp4FCJ7NTOCtvRPUBRFM2xLQxaomMi2kBRqYPE/XWXQy0UZQZNq0MiD9@bebNRYZ6PHsJwv//I0zAuIwYLnhVSMJoEA2NLWJKJ52AAgzCmRQGfeSHhRf0E9VSmL1nE5vq3fM5ZxNZQyGg2KzZUsGiZS7FARABfpXDAfjH62AF9Y@v5gfd7SSXDqPWzFpylERhFDQUfFQZStpXLeWtSTiEX7Klj4qmEiEq67FJNLILnWw9mFYio15edCxdmqSoIxhzmCNeRSe75VUD11hB3h3m9N6UnLmRJY/itScSDW1D1o2Us5wcYo22oCqw1Iv5Tv0RDLRUPX0AwWYq0ghNvXFUPdhYe07HQykgahs7V61KwfkNdPGeIqvSINwlkPFK0ggnZL6spEz75KECFOi0MTLzGMO/jLH2g8JahB7dcoW/73PZlHfcabFpQsFTylMVLTW5nDfPaMBrZpbGxdheQ0QAsFrpB1ZV6U1G1yWUotZS7JI9ZoshU8ixVM4pG37lYDrjZhJbw5jZ0Jq4VeCI3vJj3S9SRd9@kNevvhL5rhrH622mVRSE1BOVpHIn/QZpmjPs9Aue63kkmqMzEX1a2uzBSdGS3/IMbA3GdayIvVzEPZ9YiZXlNPkH9lYM2C@SPAlwoYm1gG7Fln55W6SMDB1gT681xtsvtZjRyuGnm7y03qyyLjYsPt00dWvdD7swMoXysa9ltTFsl64PSOuP1S9NDPSYEq93rNtHfoIQ@smX1vVp05ysgOg@vao721HiGFXvgqWMVG5ktEGfkPRur77@8LDbLFQ0f270z89ZIR3J1T7rV2wscqG2tL8ZdL85aZCrGYaBG4f8GGegWoduE6hoNKt@0lBls1ch8/2kWt5MfxgmzUsJiAUej4MhszxoXp6arTfds7PHrMf7bzt9w9fojrX3trIGIJ5U1noxNPci557JeO62XTuuktp6dqZ4X6is9g4kPlz5c@3CuT7Yk1qCOlmntaTpuZ4BceA7jjct45TJOD3Vc@HDjw5UP00YHgnaD/f4P)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to define a member function next() which can select between a shared or weak pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct T {
    int n_;
    shared_ptr<T> next_;
    weak_ptr<T> weaknext_;
    T(shared_ptr<T> next, int n) : next_(next), n_(n) {};
    auto next() {
         if (next_ == nullptr)
             return shared_ptr<T>(weaknext_);
         return next_;
    }
    ~T() { cout << n_ << "ok\n"; }
};
int main() {
    auto p0 = make_shared<T>(nullptr, 1);
    auto p1 = make_shared<T>(p0, 2);
    auto p2 = make_shared<T>(p1, 3);
    p0->weaknext_ = p2;  //makes the list circular
    auto p = p2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        cout << p->n_ << "\n";
        p = p->next();
    }
}
```